# Java PatternSyntaxException: Unmatched closing '('

Tags: java

I need to remove all the URLs found in Twitter messages. I have a file with around 200,000 such messages so speed is crucial! To do this I use Java as a programming language, here is an example of my code:

```
public String performStrip(){

    String tweet = this.getRawTweet();
    String urlPattern = "((https?|http)://(bit\\.ly|t\\.co|lnkd\\.in|tcrn\\.ch)\\S*)\\b";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(urlPattern,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(tweet);

    int i = 0;

    while (m.find()) {
        tweet = tweet.replaceAll(m.group(i),"").trim();
        i++;
    }

    return tweet;
}
```

This works fine in following cases:

```
http://t.co/nhWp9hldEH        -> (empty string)
http://t.co/nhWp9hldEH"       -> "
http://t.co/nhWp9hldEH)aaa"   -> aaa"
aaa(http://t.co/nhWp9hldEH"   -> aaa("
aaa(http://t.co/nhWp9hldEH)"  -> aaa()"
```

However, when I get to a case as follows:

```
http://t.co/nhWp9hldEH)aaa"
```

I get an error

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unmatched closing ')' near index 21
```

http://t.co/nhWp9hldEH)aa

```
at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1924)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1669)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1337)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1022)
at java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2210)
at com.anturo.preprocess.url.UrlStripper.performStrip(UrlStripper.java:47)
at com.anturo.preprocess.testing.ReadIn.<init>(ReadIn.java:35)
at com.anturo.preprocess.testing.Main.main(Main.java:6)
```

I already looked into multiple similar questions regarding this error, however none have worked so far... Hoping someone can help me out here.

Comment: Uhm, why don't you use the `URI` class to identify URLs? This would imho be faster than using a regex...

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: What is more: `(https?|http)` can be replaced with `https?`

Comment: I don't know the reason you do this, but this is potentially quite dangerous id someone relies on it. It won't find URIs with schemes other than http or https - and there are many[1] - and this might be used as an attack vector.

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Official_IANA-registered_schemes

Comment: @Bex, I agree but this is just to remove all the unwanted elements from Twitter messages so it can be used in my work in Natural Language Processing etc. Thanks for your remark anyway!

Comment: "so speed is crucial" - one might translate that to "so the system performance needs to be really good". Generally you fix that with hardware.

Comment: @Gimby, yes hardware is indeed a crucial part however, if my algorithm loops over the data one time too many than necessary, speed can go down significantly since I have such a large dataset. I wanted to stress this so people could suggest some minor improvements, such as fge did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you may have regex special characters in a URL, as you can see.

Short solution: use [`Pattern.quote()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29). Your code would then be:

```
tweet = tweet.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(m.group(i)),"").trim();
```

Note: only available since JDK 1.5, but you do use this or better, right?

Another solution is to simply use `.replace()`:

```
tweet = tweet.replace(m.group(i), "").trim();
```

Unlike what its name suggests with regards to `.replaceAll()`, `.replace()` *does* replace all occurrences; it is simply that it doesn't take a regex as a replacement string. See also `.replaceFirst()`.

Last but not least, you seem to be misusing `.group()`! Your loop should be:

```
while (m.find())
    tweet = tweet.replace(m.group(), "").trim();
```

No need for the `i` variable here; `m.group(i)` will, *for one match*, return what is matched by capturing group `i` in your regex.